# Como personalizar tooltip para highchart combinado (Pie, columnstack and line))

Tags: javascript, c#, asp, highcharts

Necesito personalizar los tooltip formatter de 3 tipos de graficas diferentes (pie, columnstack and line) de un hichchart en Asp.Net c#, tengo lo siguinte pero no todas las propiedas son los mimos para los tres tipos de graficas

.SetTooltip(new Tooltip
            {
                Formatter = @"function() { return '**'+ this.series.name +'**
Hora: '+ this.x +'
Produccion: '+ this.y.toFixed(2) +' m²' + '
 Porcentaje:' + Math.round(this.percentage) +'%'+ '
Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;}"
            })